# Student work correction classe

Tags: margins, enumerate

I'd like to get my students work correction look like [this page](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=73842261124883351554).

[image]

This document was written with Word (and not by me) and I have to type similar documents with the same formatting.

If I were to type this document, I'd write something like (I omit the preamble) :

```
\begin{exercice}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item \points{1,5} $\Vec{BC}(1 ; 0 ; 2)$ et $\Vec{CD}$.

    $\Vec{BC} \cdot \Vec{CD}$ sont orthogonaux donc le triangle $BCD$ est rectangle en $C$.

    Son aire se calcule donc par :
    \[
    \mathcal{A}_{BCD} = \frac{BC \times CD}{2} = \frac{\sqrt 5 \times \sqrt{70}}{2} = \frac{5\sqrt{14}}{2}
    \]

  \item
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item \points{1,5} Il suffit de montrer que $\vec n$ est orthogonal à deux vecteurs non-colinéaires de $(BCD)$, par exemple $\Vec{BC}$ et $\Vec{CD}$.

      % some more text
    \end{enumerate}

    % some more text
  \end{enumerate}
\end{exercice}
```

If possible, I'd like not to have to change my source formatting : I use mostly `enumerate` environments (sometimes imbricated, for questions 1a, 1b, etc.) for each questions, and a custom `exercice` environment for each exercice.

The difficult thing is the right-side box with the points (macro `\points`), with marks corresponding with items on the left.

I thought about using a `tabular`, but it is difficult to handle with enumerations. Also I didn't manage to make marginpars with a surrounding frame (and I had vertical alignments problems on short questions). I think the latter is the best ooption, but I need help to have the surrounding frame that spans over the entire `exercice`environment.

Also, I'm using TeX (and LaTeX) for about 20 years, I have my own set of macros and classes, so I'd rather avoid using some heavy already-made classes like exams (which I didn't know, looks great, but doesn't seem to answer completely my problem).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: did you know [exam](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam) class? I did not understand link in your question.

Comment: Sorry to have been unclear, I'm rephrasing my question to be more specific about chat causes me problems.

Comment: I understand that you want that `\points{1,5}` produces the value `1.5` appearing inside the right hand column. Is it correct?

Comment: I know how to do that (with `\marginpar`). What I don't know is how to have the frame in the margin so it spans over the entire exercise.

Comment: I see two options here: a) use a longtabular environment style `p{...}c` where each exercise is one row (but you will lose pagebreaks into exercise) or 2) use `marginpar` and then draw the rectangle using absolute positions of the page (but I see difficult to center the points vertically in the exercise)....

Comment: Other options for the box on the right are the flowfram package and tikz overlay.